# How to make a ternary operator better?

Tags: javascript

In my javascript code I have as below,

```
    ($('.field-name-field-sponsorship-image').length > 0) ? (evoJustIn.css('margin-top', '-260px')) : (evoJustIn.css('margin-top', '-300px'));
```

Yes, I am using jQuery. Why is ESLint complaining? I am guessing this is not a good practice to write ternary operator like this? What is wrong with this and how to make it better? It work.. just can't seem to understand the reasons behind ESLINT complaining...

Comment: Your question lacks the necessary context for a good review. See [ask]. Your goal is to conditionally set a CSS margin; that should be the title of the question. Also, I strongly recommend making a live demo — press Ctrl-M in the question editor — so that we can see exactly what layout your code achieves.

Comment: What you have there is a conditional expression, which always produces a value. You are not interested in that value, however. In this case, an if-statement seems more intuitive or semantically correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not the place to ask for code fix, but let me help you since its code review.

```
var sponsorshipImagesLength = $('.field-name-field-sponsorship-image').length;

var evoMarginTop = sponsorshipImagesLength > 0 ? '-260px' : '-300px';
evoJustIn.css('margin-top', evoMarginTop);
```

Now you have devided your code into smaller blocks that are more readable for you, but also for other people working on your code.